# Unable to detect the current GTK+ theme

Tags: gtk, copy.com, qgtkstyle

I've recently downloaded the app from Copy.com (a Dropbox clone). When I run it on Ubuntu 12.10 from the terminal, I get the following message/warning:

```
Expanded string ~/.copy /home/USERNAME/.copy
Expanded string ~/.copy /home/USERNAME/.copy
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
```

I know something is not working because the top bar icon of the app doesn't show. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed that by installing "libgnomeui-0" on fresh Ubuntu 15.10.

Now I have

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```